# Generate QByteArray format with Golang

Tags: qt, go, format, qbytearray

I have an application on QT which reads from a file with text in a QByteArray format (the information belongs to a certificate stored in a file). Looks like this:

> certificate="@ByteArray(0\x82\tF\x2\x1\x3\x30\x82\t\x10\x6\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x1\a\x1\xa0\x82\t\x1\x4\x82\b\xfd\x30\x82\b\xf9\x30\x82\x3\xad\x6\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x1\a\x1\xa0\x82\x3\x9e\x4\x82\x3\x9a\x30\x82\x3\x96\x30\x82\x3\x92\x6\v*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x1\f\n\x1\x3\xa0\x82\x3+0\x82\x3'\x6\n*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x1\t\x16\x1\xa0\x82\x3\x17\x4\x82\x3\x13\x30\x82\x3\xf\x30\x82\x1\xf7\xa0\x3\x2\x1\x2\x2\x1\x1\x30\r\x6\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x1\x1\x5\x5\0\x30\x16\x31\x14\x30\x12\x6\x3U\x4\x3\f\vMumble User0\x1e\x17\r200130204841Z\x17\r400125204841Z0\x16\x31\x14\x30\x12\x6\x3U\x4\x3\f\vMumble User0\x82\x1\"0\r\x6\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x1\x1\x1\x5\0\x3\x82\x1\xf\0\x30\x82\x1\n\x2\x82\x1\x1\0\xc6\x1d\x66\x8f\xc2\x31-N\xa1\xa0,\xf4\xb9\xc6\x80\x30)\xba\xf6\x17\x37\xec\x82\x1a\xf2s\xfc\xbc\x86\x93\x97\x83G\xccU(\vnr\t\xa8\x61\x12\b\x8f\xd6\x95T?\xc9\xe8\xe3v\x80%\xe3}\xe6,\x90\a\xe2\x18\xe0V\x80k\xee\x88&H <2G\x81\xec\xd6\xf1\xe9\xd0\xcat\x13\x9c?\x81\xcf\xaf\x14J\xc1X\xa5k\x9f\xf6P\xd9y\b\xa2\xe7\xaf\xa0l\xa0\xb4\xc7g\xc3*\xdd\x10\x16\xde\xe\xc3

Now I need generate the same format (QByteArray) using a GO application, but didn't find how generate this format.

Anyone can point me to some example or documentation on how create the same format of a QByteArray using another language (go)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

QByteArray is just an array of bytes, in go that would just be `[]byte`